# fstream - заполнение указанного диапазона байт определённым значением

Tags: c++

Имеется файл размер 10 байт с таким содержимым:

```
0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54 0x54
```

Необходимо в 3-й, 4-й, 5-й и 6-й байты записать значение, к примеру, 0x4C, т.е. должно получиться вот так:

```
0x54 0x54 0x54 0x4С 0x4С 0x4С 0x4С 0x54 0x54 0x54
```

Если использовать метод fstream `write()`, то в качестве аргумента необходимо передавать ссылку на буфер, содержащий необходимые для записи данные.

А есть ли у fstream метод, в который можно передать 1 целевой байт и указать количество байт, в которые необходимо записать это значение? Т.е. как-то так:

```
my_file.seekp(3, std::ios::beg);
my_file.write_bytes((char*)"\x4C", 4);
```

Comment: Да, в стандартной библиотеке не хватает множества функций. Например, чтоб вычислять вторую цифру числа справа... или для записи именно четырех байт по указанному смещению, типа `write_4bytes_at(0x4C,3);`. Ведь написать самостоятельно такое — это неимоверно сложная задача!

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю, чем так не нравится короткое и понятное

```
my_file.write("\x4C\x4C\x4C\x4C", 4);
```

но раз так, то вполне сработает

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    my_file.write("\x4C", 1);
```

или

```
for(unsigned char x = 0x4C, i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    my_file.write((const char*)&x, 1);
```

или даже

```
for(char x = 0x4C, i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    my_file.write(&x, 1);
```